# Image Transform not passing correct URL

Tags: image-transforms, image

So Right now I am working on https://munisense.com/sound, and since a week or so the Image Transform functionality seems to be working in another way (ever since the last mandatory update). 
The strangest part is that in my local/offline version of the website, the paths to the transformed images are working correctly. But online, the image paths point to the fullsized versions.
For examples, take a look at the 'services' paragraph, each of those three images isn't scaled down by Craft. Right now I solved the problem temporarily with some CSS rules, giving the images a fixed width. Just turn them off to see what it looked like when I checked it out this morning.

The syntax I am using is the following:

```
{% for image in services_info.image %}
        <img src="{{ image.getUrl('productTransform') }}" alt="{{ services_info.title }}"><br>
{% endfor %}
```

But this syntax hasn't changed for a long while now, so I think the problem is somewhere else. Also because locally the correct paths are working.

So how can it be that Craft is not applying the paths of the resized versions of my images? Where do I need to look instead to fix this?

Comment: How are you defining your transforms and what are your asset source path settings?  It looks like they aren't being ran through the asset transform process at all.  Do any other transforms on the site work?

Comment: I am defining them in the Asset section of the admin panel. One is named 'Product Transform' with the handle 'productTransform'. I also attempted to define the transform within the template itself, I tried to use the guidelines in the documentation as strictly as possible.

Comment: My asset source path settings are pretty standard, pointing to a local folder. I can't think of a way how this can cause any problems. It did work in the past though. The transformations I mean, because the website has been online for almost a year now and it was only last week that I discovered the images were completely not fitting in the layout. That's why I corrected it with CSS for now...

Comment: Are you using any soft of caching on the front end? Varnish/Cloudflare/opcache/Craft cache tags/etc?

Comment: I do use cache from Craft. I think that's it.

Comment: If you take out the `{% cache %}` tags, does it work as expected?

Comment: It does not make a difference. The image source is still the source of the full-sized image. I did clear the cache beforehand and also cleared everything in my browser. But it didn't help.